# My issue is that I am unable to make any network request in ios 13 and xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, http, alamofire

I have created an app for my client about Forex. My app was running well in IOS 12 but when i install my app on IOS 13 simulator it doesn't make any network request.

```
Alamofire.request(URL_USER_LOGIN, method: .post, parameters:params).responseJSON { response in 
    if response.result.isSuccess {

        let response : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
        if response[0]["response"].intValue == 1 {
            print("Success")
        }    
        else {
            print("Error")                    
        }
    }
    else {  
        print("Connection Error")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Alamofire to the latest version. 
If you're using cocapods you can update your pod, `pod update Alamofire`